# How to display Object information in QMainWindow

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt4

I am attempting to create a GUI with PyQt4 which allows me to create a new Employee and call the Employee's info() method. Here is the Employee class:

```
class Employee:

  def __init__(self, full_name, id, salary):
    self.full_name = full_name
    self.id = id
    self.salary = salary

  @property
  def info(self):
    return print("Employee ID:", self.id, "\nFull name:", self.full_name, "\nSalary:", self.salary)
```

Here is the code that integrates PyQt4:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4.QtGui import QInputDialog


class Employee:

  def __init__(self, full_name, id, salary):
    self.full_name = full_name
    self.id = id
    self.salary = salary

  @property
  def info(self):
    return print("Employee ID:", self.id, "\nFull name:", self.full_name, "\nSalary:", self.salary)


class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow, Employee):

  def __init__(self):
    super(Window, self).__init__()  #Returns the parrent object or the QMainWindow object
    self.setGeometry(50, 50, 500, 300)
    self.setWindowTitle("Employee builder")

    extractAction = QtGui.QAction("&Add Employee", self)
    extractAction.triggered.connect(self.create_employee)

    mainMenu = self.menuBar()
    fileMenu = mainMenu.addMenu('&File')
    fileMenu.addAction(extractAction)

    self.home()

  def home(self):
    self.show()

  def create_employee(self):
    text, ok = QtGui.QInputDialog.getText(self, 'Input Dialog',
                                          'Enter employees name:')

    ID, ok = QInputDialog.getInt(self, "integer input dualog", "Enter employees id number:")

    pay, ok = QInputDialog.getInt(self, "integer input dualog", "Enter employees salary:")

    emp1 = Employee(text, ID, pay)
    emp1.info


def run():
  app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
  GUI = Window()
  sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This code works to display the information from info() in the run window. However, what I would like to do is display the information in the QMainWindow but I am not sure how to do that.

On a side note, I don't know that the way I am going about this is the correct convention so feel free to show me the correct way if I am wrong.

Comment: That depends on how you want to show, how do you want to show it ?, there is no correct way. Your possible answers will be based on opinions, doing off-topic in SO.

Comment: @eyllanesc I guess what I was hoping was to learn a method of displaying the object's information directly in the QMainWindow.

Comment: There are multiple ways, for example using QMessageBox: `QtGui.QMessageBox.information(None, "user title", "some_information")`

Comment: change `return print("Employee ID:", self.id, "\nFull name:", self.full_name, "\nSalary:", self.salary)` to `return "Employee ID:", self.id, "\nFull name:", self.full_name, "\nSalary:", self.salary`

Comment: @eyllanesc I can get a QmessageBox to display object information? I tried: QtGui.QMessageBox.information(None, "user title", str(emp1.info)) and it displays: ('Employee ID:', 2, '\nFull name:', 'jake', '\nSalary:', 30000). What would be the correct way to call info()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to show a result, for example we can use a `QMessageBox`.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui


class Employee:
    def __init__(self, full_name, _id, salary):
        self.full_name = full_name
        self.id = _id
        self.salary = salary

    @property
    def info(self):
        return "Employee ID: {}\nFull name:{}\nSalary:{}".format(self.id, self.full_name, self.salary)


class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow, Employee):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()  #Returns the parrent object or the QMainWindow object
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 500, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle("Employee builder")

        extractAction = QtGui.QAction("&Add Employee", self)
        extractAction.triggered.connect(self.create_employee)

        mainMenu = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = mainMenu.addMenu('&File')
        fileMenu.addAction(extractAction)

    def create_employee(self):
        text, ok = QtGui.QInputDialog.getText(self, 'Input Dialog','Enter employees name:')
        ID, ok = QtGui.QInputDialog.getInt(self, "integer input dualog", "Enter employees id number:")
        pay, ok = QtGui.QInputDialog.getInt(self, "integer input dualog", "Enter employees salary:")
        emp1 = Employee(text, ID, pay)
        QtGui.QMessageBox.information(self, "New Employee", emp1.info)


def run():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Comment: @Rob 
If my answer helps you do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it, review the [tour], that is the best way to thank.

Answer (score 0):

A QMainWindow has a built in QStatusBar at the bottom of the window that you can use for short messages.

If you were to go this route, you would probably change your Employee.info to return a string, e.g.

```
return "Employee ID: " + self.id + ",  Full name: " + self.full_name + ",  Salary: " + self.salary
```

and to display the message in the status bar

```
self.statusbar.showMessage(emp.id)
```